# ClassNotFoundException in calling java from oracle procedure

Tags: java, oracle, exception, classnotfoundexception, procedure

This is my oracle `procedure` :

```
FUNCTION JavaHefExtract_runSingle (
    p_company_cd        varchar2,
    p_srcConnString     varchar2,
    p_destConnString    varchar2,
    p_mode              number,
    p_period            number
    ) return varchar2
IS
LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'HefExtract.DoIt(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, int ) return java.lang.String';
```

And this is my java `function`:

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HefExtract
{

 public static String DoIt(String orgName, String oracleConnstring, String sqlConnstring, int typ, int iPeriod )
    {
        String errMsg = null;
        Connection sqlConn;
        Connection oracleConn;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            if (oracleConnstring != null)
                oracleConn = DriverManager.getConnection(oracleConnstring);
            else
                oracleConn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
            sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlConnstring);
        } catch (Throwable e1) {
            CharArrayWriter byteSink = new CharArrayWriter();
            e1.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(byteSink));
            return byteSink.toString();
        }
        return errMsg;
}
}
```

When I call the oracle `procedure` in `PL/SQL` block this error is returned:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java)
>         at HefExtract.DoIt(HEFEXTRACT:415)

What may be the reason behind this error?

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver is Microsft SQL Driver not oracle's driver. You are getting this error because you dont have microsft sql driver on your classpath

Comment: Did you register the Java class in the Oracle server? And if you are not connecting to SQL Server, why are you loading its driver?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no need to use the Microsoft SQL Server driver in your case. Just remove everything that has to do with the Microsoft driver, i.e. delete these lines:

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this Wiki Article on how to set the classpath which has lot of examples. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)

If you are using Eclipse Select the Project -> Properties -> Project Build Path -> Java Libraries locate the jar file and select it

If you are using netbeans Select the Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Compile locate the jar and select it

This [post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:371818151299) also may help to resolve your problem

Comment: It's a server side Java function. Those are not influenced by the NetBeans or Eclipse classpath